# Reading XML file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm learning how to use Node. At this time, I have an XML file that looks like this:

**sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-10-01</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/about</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-10-01</lastmod>
    <changefreq>never</changefreq>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/articles/tips-and-tricks</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-10-01</lastmod>
    <changefreq>never</changefreq>
    <article:title>Tips and Tricks</blog:title>
    <article:description>Learn some of the tips-and-tricks of the trade</article:description>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I am trying to load this XML in my Node app. When loaded, I want to only get the `url` elements that include the use of the `<article:` elements. At this time, I'm stuck though. Right now, I'm using [XML2JS](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) via the following:

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/sitemap.xml', function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

When the `console.log` statement is executed, I just see a bunch of numbers in the console window. Something like this:

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[60,63,120, ...]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Any other reason to convert it to JSON? Using XMLDOM, XPAth for node since you know it's XML and can use XPath would be another route to consider.

Answer (score 48):

use xml2json

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json

```js
fs = require('fs');
var parser = require('xml2json');

fs.readFile( './data.xml', function(err, data) {
    var json = parser.toJson(data);
    console.log("to json ->", json);
 });
```

Comment: Small heads-up for everyone looking into XML-to-JSON transformations: xml2json library indeed worked much better for me rather than xml2js.

Comment: An other lib such as `xml-js` is able to convert in both directions. It's not when you will need this that you can. Because the inner representation in javascript is always specific in such libs. (xml -> javascript -> proper json)

Comment: It's worth noting that `parse.toJson(data)` returns a JSON string. If you want to access the results of `parse.toJson(data)` as a Javascript object you need to take one more step by calling `JSON.parse`. `const json = JSON.parse(parser.toJson(data));` gives you a primitive object so you can do `console.log(json.myPropertyKey)`.

Comment: xml2json requires Python, no thanks.

Comment: xml2json is no longer maintained. and as @user2867288 says, it uses python...

Answer (score 18):

From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback).

> The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the
>   contents of the file.
>
> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.
>
> If options is a string, then it specifies the encoding. Example:
>
> ```
> fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', 'utf8', callback);
> ```

You didn't specify an encoding, so you get the raw buffer.

Answer (score 15):

@Sandburg mentioned `xml-js` in a comment and it worked best for me (several years after this question was asked). The others I tried were: `xml2json` which required some Windows Sdk that I did not want to deal with, and `xml2js` that did not provide an easy enough OTB way to search through attributes.

I had to pull out a specific attribute in an xml file 3 nodes deep and `xml-js` did it with ease.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

With the following example file `stats.xml`

```
<stats>
  <runs>
    <latest date="2019-12-12" success="100" fail="2" />
    <latest date="2019-12-11" success="99" fail="3" />
    <latest date="2019-12-10" success="102" fail="0" />
    <latest date="2019-12-09" success="102" fail="0" />
  </runs>
</stats>
```

I used `xml-js` to find the element `/stats/runs/latest` with attribute `@date='2019-12-12'` like so

```
const convert = require('xml-js');
const fs = require('fs');

// read file
const xmlFile = fs.readFileSync('stats.xml', 'utf8');

// parse xml file as a json object
const jsonData = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(xmlFile, {compact: true, spaces: 2}));

const targetNode = 

    // element '/stats/runs/latest'
    jsonData.stats.runs.latest

    .find(x => 

        // attribute '@date'
        x._attributes.date === '2019-12-12'
    );

// targetNode has the 'latest' node we want
// now output the 'fail' attribute from that node
console.log(targetNode._attributes.fail);  // outputs: 2
```

Answer (score 5):

fs.readFile has an optional second parameter: encoding. If you do not include this parameter it will automatically return you a Buffer object.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

If you know the encoding just use:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/sitemap.xml', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: your `parser` variable is never used?

Comment: The parser variable was from the original question, I did not know how it was intended to be used from their code. Removed.

Comment: I was spending a bit of time trying to turn an xml into a string, but this is the better option. 
Alternatively use `readFileSync()`

Answer (score 4):

Install xml2js using: `npm install xml2js --save`.

```
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const fs = require('fs');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser({ attrkey: "ATTR" });

// this example reads the file synchronously
// you can read it asynchronously also
let xml_string = fs.readFileSync("data.xml", "utf8");

parser.parseString(xml_string, function(error, result) {
  if (error === null) {
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For an express server:

```
  app.get('/api/rss/', (_request: Request, response: Response) => {
    const rssFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/rssFeeds/guardian.xml', { encoding: 'utf8' })

    console.log('FILE', rssFile)

    response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    response.send(rssFile)
  })
```

- Take request
- Read File
- Set xml header
- Return file

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
npm install express-xml-bodyparser --save
```

at Client side:-

```
 $scope.getResp = function(){
     var posting = $http({
           method: 'POST',
           dataType: 'XML',
           url: '/getResp/'+$scope.user.BindData,//other bind variable
           data: $scope.project.XmlData,//xmlData passed by user
           headers: {
              "Content-Type" :'application/xml'
            },
           processData: true
           });
       posting.success(function(response){
       $scope.resp1 =  response;
       });
   };
```

on Server side:-

```
xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
app.use(xmlparser());
app.post('/getResp/:BindData', function(req, res,next){
  var tid=req.params.BindData;
  var reqs=req.rawBody;
  console.log('Your XML '+reqs);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex before parsing to remove elements not matching your conditions :

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../public/sitemap.xml', "utf8",function(err, data) {
    // handle err...

    var re = new RegExp("<url>(?:(?!<article)[\\s\\S])*</url>", "gmi")
    data = data.replace(re, ""); // remove node not containing article node
    console.log(data);
    //... parse data ...



});
```

Example :

```
   var str = "<data><url><hello>abc</hello><moto>abc</moto></url><url><hello>bcd</hello></url><url><hello>efd</hello><moto>poi</moto></url></data>";
   var re = new RegExp("<url>(?:(?!<moto>)[\\s\\S])*</url>", "gmi")
   str = str.replace(re, "")

   // "<data><url><hello>abc</hello><moto>abc</moto></url><url><hello>efd</hello><moto>poi</moto></url></data>"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to [read an XML file in Node](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/node-load-xml-file-with-xml2js), I like the [XML2JS package](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js). This package lets me easily work with the XML in JavaScript then.

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();       
parser.parseString(fileData.substring(0, fileData.length), function (err, result) {
  var json = JSON.stringify(result);
});
```

Comment: This module is too limited... can't event handle nested nodes, and returns nodes with the same tag in an array regardless of their order... WTF?

Answer (score 0):

coming late to this thread, just to add one simple tip here,
if you plan to use parsed data in js or save it as json file, be sure to set `explicitArray` to `false`. The output will be more js-friendly

so it will look like,
`letparser=newxml2js.Parser({explicitArray:false})`

Ref:
https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var convert = require('xml-js');
var xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<note importance="high" logged="true">' +
'    <title>Happy</title>' +
'    <todo>Work</todo>' +
'    <todo>Play</todo>' +
'</note>';
fs.writeFileSync(`./file.xml`,xml);
var result1 = convert.xml2js(fs.readFileSync(`./file.xml`).toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(result1,null,4));
/*
{
    "declaration": {
        "attributes": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "encoding": "utf-8"
        }
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "element",
            "name": "note",
            "attributes": {
                "importance": "high",
                "logged": "true"
            },
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "element",
                    "name": "title",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Happy"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "element",
                    "name": "todo",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Work"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "element",
                    "name": "todo",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Play"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

*/
```