# Get specific content in svg file with js

Tags: javascript, regex, svg

I need to retrieve a specific content like this "{ content }" in my svg file

So I think I need to use a regex but i don't know how to do

test.svg

```
<svg width="500" height="100">
    <text x="47.872" y="11.064" id="smartCar">{garage/temp} °C</text>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
    <text x="47.872" y="11.064" id="smartCar">{home/sensors/temp/kitchen} °C</text>
</svg>
```

findContent.js

```
    var fs = require('fs');

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync( "test.svg","UTF-8");
const lines = fileContent.split("\n");
console.log(lines);
lines.forEach((line) => {
    const topicMatch = line.match();  //need regex
            if (topicMatch) {
                console.log(topicMatch[1]) // display all content with syntax {content}
            }
})
```

Expected result:

- {garage/temp}
- {home/sensors/temp/kitchen}

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873100/reading-xml-file-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/\{[\w\/]+\}/g
```

You can test it [here](https://regexr.com/5ucb9)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const regex = /{[^{}]+}/g

const string = `<svg width="500" height="100">
    <text x="47.872" y="11.064" id="smartCar">{garage/temp} °C</text>
    <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
            style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
    <text x="47.872" y="11.064" id="smartCar">{home/sensors/temp/kitchen} °C</text>
</svg>`

console.log(string.match(regex))
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/bzV5xl/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {                        '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}]+                   any character except: '{', '}' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }                        '}'
```