# obtaining xml element in nodejs with colon on the xml

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml

i tried to obtain the xml element from xml file using xml-js library in nodejs. but when i tried to get the element inside the xml that has colon like this code below, i can't obtain the element

```xml
<gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Enve srsDimension="3" srsName="EPSG:31467">
        </gml:Enve>      
</gml:boundedBy>
```

and this is javascript code i use

```js
const convert = require('xml-js');
const fs = require('fs');

// read file
const xmlFile = fs.readFileSync('georef.xml', 'utf8');

// parse xml file as a json object
const jsonData = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(xmlFile, {compact: true, spaces: 2}));

const targetNode = jsonData.['gml:boundedBy'].['gml:Enve']
console.log(targetNode._attributes.srsName);  // outputs: 2
```

and i got this code above from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59313393/9585880)

Comment: `jsonData.['gml:boundedBy'].['gml:Enve']` is a SyntaxError, you'd need `jsonData['gml:boundedBy']['gml:Enve']`.

Comment: Take a look at the JSON generated by `convert.xml2json`. I don't know what exactly it does with elements that are in a namespace (as this one is) but I suspect it is splitting out the namespace and local parts of the name rather than just leaving it unchanged as a QName containing a colon.

Comment: @MichaelKay I didn't try it myself, but according to [this thread](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js/issues/41) OP's input should work out of the box. I suspect the SyntaxError is the only error here.

Comment: OK, I was just assuming from the question that the problem was related to the colon, especially as the OP doesn't appear to know about namespaces.