# NodeJS Load XML into Encoded String

Tags: node.js, xml, dymo

I wrote a server in NodeJS that uses [DymoJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dymojs) to print labels to a Dymo printer. When printing, the XML for the label layout must be specified. The documentation outlines the following to declare the label XML:

```
var labelXml = `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">
  ...
      <StyledText>
        <Element>
          <String>T</String>
          <Attributes>
            <Font Family="Helvetica" Size="13" 
                Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/>
            <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/>
          </Attributes>
        </Element>
        <Element>
          <String>EST123</String>
          <Attributes>
            <Font Family="Helvetica" Size="13" 
                Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False"/>
            <ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0"/>
          </Attributes>
        </Element>
      </StyledText>
</DieCutLabel>
`;
```

However in my XML, the `<String>` elements are dependent on JS variables:

```
<Element>\
   <String>${name}\n</String>\
   ...
</Element>\
```

The server I wrote is distributed across multiple endpoints, which use different printers, and therefore different labels, meaning they require different XML specifications.

**What I would like, is to be able to load the basic XML from a document, and then replace `${name}` and other variables with their JS counterparts.** I tried to use a raw `fs.readfile()`, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32873154/5790193), which did not work, as the XML was not parsed as encoded (or that is my best guess as to what went wrong). Most of the rest of the questions I've found are either relating to Site-Mapped-JS, or end up converting the XML to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use [xml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js)?

You can edit structure as js objects and then translate it to xml.

For example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const convert = require('xml-js');

const xml = fs.readFileSync('prueba.xml');
const js = convert.xml2js(xml, {compact: true});

js['DieCutLabel']['StyledText']['Element'][0]['String'] = 'Value of name';

console.log(convert.js2xml(js, {compact: true}));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm giving it some TLC dev work now and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: It worked :) Thanks for the assist o7